# Sql Query Not Like is not Working

Tags: sql

```
select
    a.ID, a.FirstName, a.LastName, a.PhoneNumber,
    a.EmailAddress, a.Website, a.isEmailSubscriptionActive
  from
    Contacts a,
    BlockedEmailDomains b
  where
    a.ID  in (3574,3577,3571,3579,3578) and
    a.EmailAddress Not like '%'+b.DomainName+'%'
```

This is the query i have written. Not Like is not working for me... Whats the wrong with this code.

Comment: What is your database? MySQL? MSSQL? Oracle? What is the result you're getting and what would you expect instead?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Define "not working."  What is a sample of the data being queried and what is the result from that sample?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago). With your current query (which defines **no JOIN condition** between the two tables), you'll get a **cartesian product** (each row from `Contacts` joined to each row of `BlockedEmailDomains`) - maybe that's the **root cause** of your problem?$

Comment: @SimonKrenger: must be SQL Server or MySQL due to the non-standard string concatenation operator `+`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: and since no "backticks" are used on the column names, my guess would be SQL Server - but we shouldn't have to guess - the OP should **tell us** up front what he's using!

Comment: You probably want `NOT EXISTS ... LIKE` rather than `NOT LIKE`

Answer (score 0):

You should have mentioned at least what your query is supposed to do. I assume you are trying to select all contacts where the domain is not blocked? This is an exists query; you are looking for all contacts where no blocking entry *exists*:

```
select
  a.ID, a.FirstName, a.LastName, a.PhoneNumber,
  a.EmailAddress, a.Website, a.isEmailSubscriptionActive
from
  Contacts a
where
  a.ID in (3574,3577,3571,3579,3578)
  and not exists
  (
    select *
    from BlockedEmailDomains b
    where a.EmailAddress like '%'+b.DomainName+'%' 
  )
;
```

BTW: Are EmailAddress and DomainName guaranteed to have the same upper and lower case? Otherwise you should use lower() or upper() when comparing them.